# How can I deserialize an array inside a JSON object?

Tags: java, json, gson

I can't work out how to deserialize an array inside a JSON object using Gson.  The json object that i'm trying to deserialize looks like this:

```
{"item0":3,
 "item1":1,
 "item2":3,
 "array":[
    {"arrayItem1":321779321,
     "arrayItem2":"asdfafd",
     "arrayItem3":"asasdfadf"}]}
```

I manage to build a class that looks like this:

```
public class Watchlist {
 private int itemn0;
 private int itemn1;
 private int itemn2;
 private Object array;

}
```

But when gson tries to deserialize the array it throws an exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Type information is unavailable, and the target object is not a primitive: <my gson array>
```

Can someone please tell me how to deserialize this?

Comment: Can you show us your code which is throwing this exception?

Comment: The code that throws the exception is just a fromJson call

Watchlist watchlist = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, Watchlist.class);

Answer (score 1):

your "array" is an Array.
so in watchList class

```
    public class Watchlist {
    private int itemn0;
    private int itemn1;
    private int itemn2;
    private List<watchListarray> array;

 //constructor
  //getter & setter of all

}

now watchListarray class
 public class watchListarray{
  String arrayItem1="";
  String arrayItem2="";
  String arrayItem3="";
//constructor 
 //getter & setters of all
}
```

Now use download Gson
refer: http://primalpop.wordpress.com/2010/06/05/parsing-json-using-gson-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems here:

One, I don't think you're using the array like you think you are. You have "arrayItem1" through 3, but they are contained in a single JSON object within the array... so the array actually only has one item.

The array should probably be something like:

```
"array": [
  321779321,
  "asdfafd",
  "asasdfadf"
]
```

The second is that the type of `array` in your Java class is `Object`... that doesn't give Gson any type information to use for translating the object. Normally, you'd want to declare the type of the object the array maps to as `List<String>` or `List<Integer>` or some such. This gives it the necessary type information... a JSON array can map to a `List`, and the `String` type parameter tells it what type to translate the array's contents to.

The problem with the array in your example is that it isn't homogenous... it has a number and two strings in it. Generally, mixing types like this in an array/collection should be avoided. You can, however, declare the type of your `array` object as `List<String>`... you'll just get the `String` form of the number.

Comment: Ah yea. Thanks for pointing that out.  You are right.  This array only has 1 item.  A better example would have been:

{"item0":3,
 "item1":1,
 "item2":3,
 "array":[
    {"arrayItem1":321779321,
     "arrayItem2":"asdfafd",
     "arrayItem3":"asasdfadf"},
     {"arrayItem1":234,
      "arrayItem2":"asdfafd",
      "arrayItem3":"asdfa"}]}

Comment: ColinD, Thanks for the explanation.  Based on what you said I managed to get the above code working by having converting my array in to a List<HashMap<String,String>>.  

but I was wondering if I could convert that into a List<MyObject>? Is that not possible at all based on your explanation?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you defined a class that has fields that correspond to the fields of the JSON objects in your array (`MyObject`) and declare the array field as `List<MyObject>`, that will work fine!

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to give it another try. The API i'm calling just threw me another JSON curve ball.  One of the values of the object in the array is another array!  

I think i may have picked the worse API to learn JSON on.  sigh.

Comment: Is there documentation for the API you're calling that tells you exactly what to expect from each object? You just need to make a Java type that matches up with the format of each JSON object you may receive and then nest them as expected from the API.

Comment: Unfortunately not. But i'll just have to work through the problems I guess.

Comment: Using the List<MyObject> type in the deserialization I'm getting an exception

com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@1cfb549 failed to deserialized json object [{"ListingId":111111111,"Title":"first title"},{"ListingId":2222222222,"Title":"second title"},{"ListingId":33333333,"Title":"third title"}] given the type com.google.gson.ParameterizedTypeImpl@5c1343

I've defined by the parent object as

Comment: My objects now look like 

My code for my object is now

public class Watchlist {
 private int itemn0;
 private int itemn1;
 private int itemn2;
 private List<MyObject> array;

}

And MyObject looks like

public class MyObject{
 private int ListingId;
 private String Title;
}

It looks right to me so I don't understand why I'm getting an exception.  It works if I revert back to List<HashMap<String,String>>.

Comment: It would help if you'd edit your question to include that information. It isn't really readable in a comment.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've decided to give this a rest for now and just use xpath. not as convenient but at least I can get it work.  Thanks for your help.