# Java JSON pulling value from selected name in JSONObject from JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to pull a value from a name in a JSONbject that is created from a JSONArray, the JSONAarray is created from the main(root) JSONObject.

Here's the JSON:

```
{"filelist": [{
"1": {
    "filename": "sample.mp3",
    "baseurl": "http://etc.com/"
}}]}
```

I'm fairly sure the JSON is correctly formatted.

Here is the Java (for Android SDK, this is in the OnCreate method in main Activity class):

```
    String jsonString = new String("{\"filelist\": [{ \"1\": { \"filename\": \"sample.mp3\", \"baseurl\": \"http://etc.com/\" }}]}");
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(jObj.getJSONArray("filelist").toString());
JSONObject jSubObj = new JSONObject(jArr.getJSONObject(0).toString());
textView1.setText(jSubObj.getString("filename"));
```

Thanks for taking a look and any answers are much appreciated.

Comment: You want to retrieve filename from the above json object ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I put in the wrong code. I will update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably want to simplify the JSON structure, but you can read it now as follows:

```
JSONObject jObj;
try {
  jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
  JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("filelist");
  JSONObject jObj2 = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
  textView1.setText(jObj2.getJSONObject("1").getString("filename"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you are going to have consecutive numbers in the JSON array, then you might consider eliminating them:

```
{"filelist": [
  {
    "filename": "sample.mp3",
    "baseurl": "http://etc.com/"
  }
]}
```

Would require one less step:

```
JSONObject jObj;
try {
  jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
  JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("filelist");
  JSONObject jObj2 = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
  textView1.setText(jObj2.getString("filename"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean by simplifying the JSON, but in the future there will be more files listed in the JSON. I am planning on using a "for" loop to parse them. Thanks again friend, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @SpicyKarl of course, that's why is an array. I'm just saying you don't need the numbering labels, e.g. `{"array":[{"item1"}{"item2"}{"item3"}]}`

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean. I will simplify the JSON as you suggest, this will help me parse multiple entries in the JSONArray. Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 2):

For Getting Single Value You can use JSONTokener:

`JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener("JSON String").nextValue();

            String lstatus=object.getString("filename");`

Answer (score 1):

may this help to u
[How can I deserialize an array inside a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951491/how-can-i-deserialize-an-array-inside-a-json-object/5271807#5271807)

Comment: Thank you but I would like to do this without gson. I have added gson to my resources and have been looking at examples, but haven't found a simpler way to do this without gson.

Comment: ya to parse json is quite complex, but with the help of Gson it is very easy dear

Answer (score 0):

e.g. to retrieve filename from above json string

```
try {
            String jsonString = new String("{\"filelist\": [{ \"1\": { \"filename\": \"sample.mp3\", \"baseurl\": \"http://www.hostchick.com/deemster/\" }}]}");
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray jArr;
            jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("filelist");
            JSONObject jobj = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
            String filename =  jobj.getJSONObject("1").getString("filename");
            Toast.makeText(this, filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```